# problemas al visualizar imagen en flutter

Tags: flutter

tengo una imagen por url pero ya probe muchas alternativas, pero ninguna abre la imagen, además que se congela mi screen dejo el link de la imagen,

PD: A veces si funciona, pero luego al cambiar de imagen se congela y no muestra nada, aquí las imágenes que voy a utilizar y que al cambiarla se congela y termina sin visualizar ninguna imagen:
https://alegrialoteria.com/files/billetes/Sorteo4_1634.jpg,

https://alegrialoteria.com/files/billetes/Sorteo1_3907.jpg,

https://alegrialoteria.com/files/billetes/Sorteo2_2785.jpg

probe ya eh probado con muchas dependencias y sucede lo mismo, acudo a ustedes para resolver la duda.
probe con

```
 Html(data: '<img src="https://alegrialoteria.com/files/billetes/Sorteo4_1634.jpg" width="200" height="200">'),
```

y ademas con

```
Image(image: NetworkImage("https://alegrialoteria.com/files/billetes/Sorteo1_3907.jpg")),
```

y tampoco funciono con:

```
child: Image.network('https://alegrialoteria.com/files/billetes/Sorteo1_3907.jpg',),
```

de igual manera:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: 'https://alegrialoteria.com/files/billetes/Sorteo1_3907.jpg',
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error), // Widget en caso de error
)
```

probe en postman y funciona sin problemas la url.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

simplemente tuve que ir al menú de la izquierda y desmarcar la opciones que se muestran en la imagen, ya pude utilizar todas las opciones antes mencionadas

Comment: ¿Cuáles son las "opciones que se muestran en la imagen"? Recuerda que [no todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).